# Comparing a string and its abbreviation for validity

Tags: java, string, algorithm, string-matching

This problem was presented to me in a job interview, and I thought it was nice because there are a few ways to solve it.

The description is as follows:

- A String such as "*internationalization*" is 20 character long. It
  can be abbreviated as "*i18n*", which reads as "*i - skip 18 characters - n*".
- Similarly, other abbreviations such as "*i16ion*", "*internationali2tion*" and even "*20*" are accepted.
- The number to skip can be any positive integer (no 0, no negative
  numbers), and the string may include more than one skip occurrence -
  for instance, "*int3ationa2za1ion*" is acceptable as well.
- The original string contains no digits - so every number in the abbreviated string represents a skip.
- The abbreviated string can begin or end with a skip as well - "*6ationalizati2*", for
  example.

Given two strings - one representing the original string, the other the abbreviation, determine if the abbreviated string is valid. The method to do this must implement the signature

```
public static boolean equals (String orig, String abbr);
```

Comment: I suppose you're not interested in knowing that this can be done in a single line of code?  I'll post an answer if I have time later.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I would actually love to know if this could be done more efficiently.

Comment: If the interviewer gave me this signature, I would have said that I thought `equals` was a poor choice of method name.  This doesn't match the concept of equality at all, because you could have two `orig` strings that are "equal [not really]" to the same `abbr`, but are not equal to each other.  `isAbbreviationFor` or `isValidAbbreviation` would be better.

Comment: @ajb to put this more formally: this method would be reflexive, but not symmetrical or transitive.

Comment: @ajb - fiar enough. Although I would prefer not to correct my interviewer in this scenario.

Comment: @Assafs I think that's an entirely valid thing to point out to an interviewer. It shows deeper understanding of concepts involved, not just blindly following instructions.

Comment: Well, I need to double-check the details and write some kind of explanation, but it's something like `return orig.matches(abbr.replaceAll("([1-9][0-9]*)", "\\w{$1}"));`

Comment: There is no comparing in the method, what if input like `internationalization` or `internatiozzzzzzzzzn` the output would be the same `i18n`?

Or you will go trough convert chars it self to hexdecimal value? 

I think the question is about how to thinking about the issue not about just implementing it.

Comment: @Ibrahim, if the input is "internationalizzzzzz" then "i18n" will not be a valid abberviation - because the 20th character of "internationalizzzzzz" is not "n". The idea is to create a validator for the abbreviation, to see if it's a correct abbreviation of the original string. You are right that there are many strings that could fit "i18n" abbreviation just as well, for example "informationalization". We are just matching string here.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem but by that method, ["i18n" isn't an abbreviation of "i18n"](https://ideone.com/Ws7kLn); but a string ought to be an abbreviation of itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't think it's supposed to be.  The spec says that the original string contains no digits.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem ah, fair enough. Missed that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really shouldn't answer this because you haven't shown your code, but I can't resist because the code is so cool:

```
public static boolean equals (String orig, String abbr) {
    return orig.matches(abbr.replaceAll("\\d+", ".{$0}"));
}
```

This works by converting all digits into their regex equivalent of a dot with a quantifier, eg:

```
"i16ion" -> "i.{16}ion"
```

`\d+` means "one or more digits (greedy)" and `$0` is a back reference to the entire match.

FYI java's `String.matches()` method must match the *whole* string, so you don't even need leading `^` or trailing `$` that you would in many other languages that return true if it matches only *part* of the string.

Comment: Why not? It's a fantastic answer. Apparently this is the key to good job interview questions: separate the coder who gives a 30 line answer from the one who gives a 1-line answer :)

Comment: This is more or less Dawood ibn Kareem's suggestion, no?

Comment: @m69 yes, but less rather than more (I didn't read the comments)

Comment: Cool.  I've upvoted you because you've saved me the trouble of writing it up for myself (which I honestly intended to do).

Comment: This is exactly what regexps are good at, so knowing that and how to get there show well-acquaintedness with the more obscure parts of the modern Java runtime library.